# How to add a TreeView control in windows store app?

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

i know there is no TreeView control in Windows store app 
Is there any alternative way to get TreeView control in Windows store app?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **winRT XAML Toolkit**. It provides many controls for us, such as TreeView, ImageButton and so on.

The link is here: [winRT XAML Toolkit.](https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/)